# MySql - Insert row for each ID of other table

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is simple I just cant get the correct search terms to find the answer.
But I have one table for locations with IDs

```
ID| Name

1 | Foo

2 | Bar

3 | Blah
```

and another table (table2) that has a field referencing those location IDs:

```
ID| LocationID | Foo | Bar

1 | 1          | ... | ...

2 | 2          | ..

3 | 5          | ...
```

Where LocationId = a value from location.
What I want to do is for every ID in location (1,2,3...) add a record to the other table.
So for example:

```
"insert into table2 (locationID, foo, bar) values (1, "hello", "world");"

"insert into table2 (locationID, foo, bar) values (2, "hello", "world");"
```

and so on..

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html), so for your example

```
INSERT INTO table2 (locationID, foo, bar) SELECT ID, 'hello', 'world' FROM table1
```

Comment: Oh ok, I was trying something like that but I figured "Select ID, 'Hello', 'world'" was trying to select all three of those values from the 1st table not just the ID.

Comment: `SELECT ID, 'hello', 'world'` maybe seems a bit weird but selects the column `ID` and the plain values 'hello' and 'world'. You can see for yourself by executing `SELECT ID, 'hello', 'world' FROM table1` (so the part without the `INSERT INTO`) to check whats will be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an Insert... Select

```
Insert Table2 (LocationID, Foo, Bar)
Select ID, "Hello", "World"
From Location
```

Comment: `Insert into` instead of just `Insert`, and ommit the `values`